# How to get Magento 2 Customizable Options with REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have customizable options in configurable products. How can I get it via REST API?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can retrieve product custom options with this API :

**catalogProductCustomOptionRepositoryV1**

"Get the list of custom options for a specific product"

```
get /V1/products/{sku}/options
```

for demo to check with create product using custom options - http://brijeshtech.in/magento-2-create-product-custom-options-by-rest-api/

**hope its very helpful to you**